# firebase3 integration in swift faces problems

Tags: ios, swift, git, firebase

I'd like to ask you a question that has taken me  few weeks to solve yet I couldn't figure it out . I am trying to install Firebase3 in my project . after I hit the command " pod install " it starts the installation but at the end it gives me the following error .

```
> [!] Unable to add a source with url
> `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master`. You can try
> adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.
```

Then I tried to go to ~/.cocoapods and clone the link directly

```
git clone  https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master
```

and I faced this error

```
> remote: Counting objects: 733146, done. remote: Compressing objects:
> 100% (5/5), done. error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSLRead() return error
> -9806.00 KiB/s    fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly fatal: early EOF fatal: index-pack failed
```

I would strongly appreciate if u can help to solve this problem :)

Comment: If you can't clone link directly then It should be temporary error with server, My project has Firebase but not giving problem

Comment: Can you post you entire `Podfile`?

Comment: @DanialKosarifa can you stuff this in your answer please, it's difficult to read in the comment

Comment: @Chris there u go ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
   > # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project  platform :ios, '9.0'
    > 
    > target 'cocoapodsTesting' do   pod ‘Firebase’   use_frameworks!
    > 
    >   # Pods for cocoapodsTesting
    > 
    >   target 'cocoapodsTestingTests' do
    >     inherit! :search_paths
    >     # Pods for testing   end
    > 
    >   target 'cocoapodsTestingUITests' do
    >     inherit! :search_paths
    >     # Pods for testing   end
    > 
    > end
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase the HTTP buffer //Double the size

`git config http.postBuffer 524288000`

and still getting the issue, please 
Please open the terminal and execute this

`git config --global user.email "youremail@xxx.xxx"`
then try

`pod setup` or `pod install`

Comment: Thanks for your respond , but I've already solved the problem simply by downgrading my Cocoa Pod `version` and then it worked as usual . To be honest I wasnt convinced why and how but it worked well XD

Comment: It will work with the latest version if wanted to try :)

Comment: Sure  I'll give it a shot ;)